# Failed to import a module in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using reactjs and es6 and I defined a javascript as below.

```
vendor.jsx:
export const VENDOR_LIST = [{
    vendor: []
}];
```

In another javasript file, I want to import this file, so I used below code. But I always got VENDOR_LIST is undefined error in componentDidMount() method. What wrong with my code?

```
import VENDOR_LIST from  '../data/vendor'

    export class VendorList extends React.Component{

  selectChanged(e){
    console.log('select changed ', e);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('load vendor list data ',VENDOR_LIST);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <select onChange={this.selectChanged}>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">A</option>
        <option value="-">Other</option>
      </select>
      )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better explain how import statements work in ES6, in short it has to do with how the `export` is done in the file.

If you export with a `default`, then you can import it like you did using any named variable as that is what it is getting assigned to:

```
const foo = 'FOO';
export default foo;

import otherFoo from '/the/file';
```

Notice how I don't use curlies and I define it with any name I want.

Now if you export multiple things without the default:

```
export const foo = 'FOO';
export const bar = 'BAR';

import { foo, bar as otherBar } = from '/the/file';
```

Now you see that you HAVE to import them with their declared names in the file and using curlies. If you wanted to assign to a different variable you can always use the `as` notation.

Comment: this is a better answer, we gotta let him do some work though! upvote from me

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about ES6 import/export. In your code, try this :

```
import { VENDOR_LIST } from  '../data/vendor'
```

Comment: great it works. Why should I need to add {} on this? I didn't do it when importing a class.

Comment: I  suggest you take a look as this article about ES6 module. Short answer: replace this in vendor.jsx `export default [{
    vendor: []
}];`